# Eclipse modeling

Tags: eclipse, uml, code-generation

I search for tool that can generate code from UML diagram for Eclipse. The tool should generate code from UML diagram, reverse engeneering to see code changes, and merge option to prevent the deletion of the file for any change.

Is there tool that do that, or is it too much to ask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like Eclipse based tools, I could recommend the free Uml to Java generator from Obeo, which may be downloaded from the Marketplace:

Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...

[image]
However, I think that it doesn´t completely fit your needs, since I believe that it doesn´t provide reverse engineering facilities. Also note that they use Acceleo for code generation, which is the reference [OMG specification implementation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Acceleo).

Comment: Hi@ASBH !  is there an introductory example about converting UML diagram to code in java using Acceleo ?

Comment: @ASBH The generate code very nice, but looks not so good... There are too many comments inside... Is there way to delete them?